# jQuery Validate - Set all fields as required by default?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validate plugin on my form, and was wondering how I would set every field to be required by default?

I am using a custom method called 'methodname' and I tried the following code to no avail:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    methodname : true
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick'n'dirty fix:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform input, #myform textarea').not([type="submit"]).addClass('required');
});
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to do it within the plugin's rules without altering the mark-up, but I couldn't find a way.. So you win! :) Thanks

Comment: Why is this dirty?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu because it modifies the DOM

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick, and doesn't require any alteration to the markup:

```
$("#myform input, #myform textarea").each(function () {
  $(this).rules("add", {
    required: true // Or whatever rule you want
  });
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#rules.28.C2.A0.22add.22.2C.C2.A0rules_.29

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered already, and this answer kind of goes along with what @vzwick posted.

```
$('form :input').not(':image, :button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, .notRequired').addClass('required');
```

Any field that you may still want to **not** require, like Address Line 2, you can add the class `.notRequired`. Other than that, this bit of code will exclude any image buttons, buttons, submits, resets, and hidden form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Add validation js in your page and 
 1. Get all names of input, textarea and select fields through loop.
 2. Create dynamic rules array
 3. Pass the rules array in validate();

```
var rules_set={};
    $('#my-form').find('input').each(function(){
        var name=$(this).attr('name');
        rules_set[name]='required';
    });
    $("#my-form").validate({
        rules: rules_set,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```